# Can Anyone help me to edit firebase rules for an ecommerce app like amazon

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Can anyone help me to edit firebase rules for an ecommerce app as i'm getting a mail from firebase saying ur firebase rules are insecure.I need them for firebase firestore.

Answer (score 3):

**For development only, you can use this. NOT FOR PRODUCTION**

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
      // EVERYUSER CAN EDIT AND DELETE YOUR DATA. NOT FOR PRODUCTION.
    }
  }
}
```

When you understand how firestore rules work, this should guide you.

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    function isLoggedIn() {
      return request.auth != null;
    }
    function isOwner() {
      // where ownerId is the id of the owner
      return isLoggedIn() && resource != null && (resource.data.ownerId == request.auth.uid);
    }

    match /posts/{postId} {
      // for an ecommerce app, 
      // everybody should be able to view posts
      allow read: if true;
      // only logged in users should be able to create posts
      allow create: if isLoggedIn();
      // only the owner of a post should be able to edit/delete posts
      allow update, delete: if isOwner();
    }
    match /users/{userId} {
      // You should be able to get, edit and delete only your data
      allow get, write: if isOwner();
      // no body should be able to get list of your users
      allow list: if false;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If things are working as expected on our side, those first rules should actually be trigger the message that OP is getting. If they're not doing that, that would be a bug in our detection of insecure rules. I still upvoted your answer because the second set of rules is solid . I love seeing readable function names like that.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Those first rules should actually trigger the message. Sorry, that skipped my mind. I guess I should delete the first set of rules. Thank you very much. I aim to please.